# What is the fundamental reason behind electric potential decreasing in the direction of increasing electric field? Is there any exception to this?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, conventions

Does this increase and decrease necessarily have to be linear in nature? I have seen this statement being thrown around which states that in direction of increasing electric field the potential decreases... but this doesn't seem to hold for field and potential of a sphere... (both of them fall off with distance... one linearly and the other as an inverse square)

Comment: “Do” what? End of thought process? Bit missing?

Comment: Actually it was 'does this increase and decrease necessarily be  linear in nature'

Comment: Can’t be as the title has not changed...

Comment: A close look at Maxwell's equations will make you see the answers.

Comment: like charges repel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the fundamental reason behind electric potential decreasing in
> the direction of increasing electric field? Is there any exception to
> this?

Whether or not electric potential increases or decreases depends on the source of the field and the polarity of the charge placed in the field.

The following assumes that when you say "in the direction of increasing electric field"  you mean in the direction that the electric field strength increases. In terms of representing the field by electric lines of flux, that is direction where the density of the electric field lines increases.

Let's take the case of the electric field generated by a fixed point positive fixed point charge. (See bottom figure to the left).The direction of the field is, by convention, the direction of the force that a positive test charge would experience if placed in the field, which is a direction away from the source charge. As you move away from the fixed positive charge, the relative density of the field lines decreases by convention.

If you put a positive test charge in that field, it will naturally move away from the source charge (repulsive force) in the direction of decreasing electric field strength. Its electrical potential will be *decreasing.*

But if you put a negative charge in the field it will require external work to move it in the direction of the field away from the positive source charge. Its potential therefore increases (external work is needed to move the charge.)

The above being said, you do not need an increasing or decreasing electric field to have an increase or decrease in electrical potential. An example is the uniform field between positive an negatively charged conductive plates separated by a small distance relative to the size of the plates. (See bottom figure to the right). The field is constant between the plates. In moving from the negative plate to the positive plate the electrical potential increase. Thus if a positive charge moves in the direction of the positive plate, its potential energy increases. If moved toward the negative plate, its potential energy decreases. The reverse is the case if a negative charge is placed between the plates.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: @AaronStevens Got a point. But our answers don't say that there necessarily needs to by a change in field strength in order for electrical potential to increase or decrease (the converse(?) of the OPs question). Example is the uniform field between a positively charge sheet of charge and negatively charged sheet of charge. Moving a charge in that field increases or decreases its potential. I probably should revise my answer to point that out. Thanks.

Comment: We don't define potential of a charge , we define potential of a point

Comment: though we define potential energy of charge

Comment: @LalitTolani I'm aware of that, but I see that my second to last sentence appears to say that. See my revision. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

By definition:

$$\mathbf E=-\nabla V$$

Or in 1D
$$E=-\frac{\text d V}{\text d x}$$

So if you move in the direction of the electric field then the potential will decrease. But this doesn't say anything about how the change in magnitude of the field relates to the change in the potential (the left side isn't $\text dE/\text dx$). The field could be getting larger, smaller, or even remaining constant as you follow it, but the potential would still be decreasing. Similarly, the field could be getting larger, smaller, or remaining constant as potential increases (just move backward in the cases from before).

Therefore, as you move through space you cannot say, in general, that there is a link between the change in electric field magnitude and the change in potential that you observe. The closest thing to what you say that I can think of that is correct is the following: **As you move in the direction of the electric field the potential decreases.**